# zipfile.ZipFile(doc) not creating word/document - textract

Tags: python, python-3.x

i am using textract to convert doc/docx file to text
here is my method

```
def extract_text_from_doc(file):
    temp = None
    temp = textract.process(file)
    temp = temp.decode("UTF-8")
    text = [line.replace('\t', ' ') for line in temp.split('\n') if line]
    return ''.join(text)
```

I have two doc files both with docx extension. when i try to convert one file to string it is working fine but for other one it is throwing exception

```
'There is no item named \'word/document.xml\' in the archive'
```

I tried to look further and i found that **zipfile.ZipFile(docx)** is causing the problem
Code looks like this

```
def process(docx, img_dir=None):
    text = u''

    # unzip the docx in memory
    zipf = zipfile.ZipFile(docx)
    filelist = zipf.namelist()

    # get header text
    # there can be 3 header files in the zip
    header_xmls = 'word/header[0-9]*.xml'
    for fname in filelist:
        if re.match(header_xmls, fname):
            text += xml2text(zipf.read(fname))

    # get main text
    doc_xml = 'word/document.xml'
    text += xml2text(zipf.read(doc_xml))
    # some more code
```

In the above code, for the file(for which it is working) returns filelist with values like 'word/document.xml', 'word/header1.xml'
but for the file(for which it is not working) its returns filelist with values

```
['[Content_Types].xml', '_rels/.rels', 'theme/theme/themeManager.xml', 'theme/theme/theme1.xml', 'theme/theme/_rels/themeManager.xml.rels']
```

since second filelist dont contain 'word/document.xml'

```
doc_xml = 'word/document.xml'
text += xml2text(zipf.read(doc_xml))
```

is throwing exception(internally it try to open file name with word/document.xml)

can anyone please help me. i dont know its problem with docx file or code.

Comment: 1. Try to unzip your file manually and look  at the contents. 2. Are you sure you're working with a `docx` file and not a `doc` file?

Comment: @Chillie i am not passing the zip file, just passing file path(actual docx file path not zip). its library code which creates the zip internally. also i am sure i am using docx file.

Comment: Docx file is just an archive that contains a lot of xml files inside it. What I'm saying to you need to inspect the file manually. Use 7zip or any other archive tool to unzip the docx file. Make sure it really is a proper docx file. And not something else with a changed extension. A docx file will have certain file structe.

Comment: I tried unzipping, it did not contain a word folder, it only contains theme, .rels folder, and '[Content_Types].xml' file
but when i unzipped other Docx files it has word folder. what should i do?@Chillie

Comment: I mean that's it. You have a broken file. It is unusable. Try contacting the person who sent you this file.

Comment: but i can open the file in word or libre office

Comment: Then try to resave it. Does it only heave headers or footers?

Comment: No, it is 5 page resume with header, footer and document

Comment: It is one of the processes of the product of the company where i work. from the candidate's resumes, we extract the name, email, mobile, etc.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234201/discussion-between-ketan-suthar-and-chillie).